# Search and replace full content lines from shell script

Tags: shell, sed

I have 2 WordPress files (`php`) from a plugin that whenever them update, I'd like to get a auto fix for some lines that best applies for me.

I'm running my website in CentOS and I have full control of the machine, so I can run shell scripts via Cron for automated task.

How can I search and replace (not by line numbers, since it's a third party plugin and the owner may change things from place, since it's a customization only for my website I can't ask for "bug fix", since it's not a bug, but an improvement for my website). I will short the mods since it will be tons of mods to apply for these 2 files and I just need an idea of how to do this.

class-recovery.php

Search for: `function dump_files( $warning = false ) {` and replace with: `function dump_files( $warning = false ) { $cancel_order;`

class-prompt.php

Search for: `private $replace_only;` and replace with: `private $replace_only = true;`

How can I get this done? I was browsing StackOverFlow and some users suggest to use `sed` for search and replace, but since this is not text only but `php` files, would this `sed` applies to? Or is there a better solution for this?

--EDIT
How could this work for multiple line search and replace using SED? I was using the traditional way but it doesn't replace when it's 2 lines (and above) indented. Example:

```
if ( empty( $donot_dump ) ) {
                return false;
```

to something like:

```
if ( empty( $donot_dump ) ) {
                return true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of-course `sed` can be applied to any text file formats for that matter. All you need to do is use the syntax `s/orignial/replace` syntax for search and replacement. And if you use `-i` syntax, it will replace the contents of the file directly. So all you need is

```
sed -i.bak "s/function dump_files( \$warning = false ) {/function dump_files( \$warning = false ) { \$cancel_order;/g" class-recovery.php
```

and for the second file

```
sed -i.bak "s/private \$replace_only;/private \$replace_only = true;/g" class-prompt.php
```

Normally we use `'` (single-quotes) around arguments of `sed`, but since we have spaces around the source string we need to preserve it, double-quoting the string does that. Also with double-quotes variables preceding a `$` have a special meaning, i.e. the shell treats them as variables and tries to expand it. We need to escape it with a `\` to let know it is not a variable but a literal word.

The `-i.bak` is to enable storing a copy of the file under the extension `.bak` and replace the original, so that if `sed` does not replace your file content as intended, you can always restore it with this file.

Remove the `.bak` and just keep as `-i` if you don't want the backup files stored.

---

If your replacement string needs a new line character use `\\n` and usual spaces to have the formatting as needed. For e.g.

```
sed "s/function dump_files( \$warning = false ) {/function dump_files( \$warning = false )\\n { \$cancel_order;/g" file
```

produces an output as below

```
function dump_files( $warning = false )
 { $cancel_order;
```

Comment: Great! Thank you buddy :)